# Why is a child class' implementation used when initialising?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

Created two classes `A` and `B` where `B` subclasses `A`. When trying to init `B` it calls `[super init]` Why does the super class `A` use the child's (`B`)'s implementation of `printMessage` ?

```
@implementation A

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self printMessage:@"Foo"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)printMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    NSLog(@"From A: %@", message);
}

@end
```

Implementation of B (Subclasses A)

```
@implementation B

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self printMessage:@"Bar"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)printMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    NSLog(@"From B: %@", message);
}

@end
```

Initialised using:

`B *b = [[B alloc] init]`

Expected output:

```
From A: Foo
From B: Bar
```

Actual output:

```
From B: Foo
From B: Bar
```

Comment: You haven't bothered reading the Objective-C programming guide have you.

Comment: @trojanfoe Nice and constructive commenting there...

Comment: I don't need to be constructive at all.  **You** need to search before posting pointless questions.

Comment: @trojanfoe and you haven't read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @trojanfoe You're assuming.

Comment: @MichałCiuba You're right; I haven't read that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing an object of type `B`.  The search for method implementations starts in class `B` and uses overridden methods if they are found, only dropping back to parent implementations otherwise.

Your `B`'s `printMessage` would have to explicitly call `[super printMessage: message]` for it to be invoked...just like the call to `init`.

---

Try putting this inside `A`'s `init` to clarify things:

```
    NSLog(@"I'm a %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
```